# Google Sheets transposing multiple column data into row

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWOec.png]

I need to transpose the left table data into the right table data in Google Sheets. I don't know which formula to use

Comment: Have you already tried `=TRANSPOSE(A1:N5)` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how to obtain result dataset or you just want to know the function in spreadsheet that does the transpose?  If it is about the function then above formula should work, given that you've changed `spreadsheet settings` for  `iterative calculation` to "ON" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={"ID", "Task", "Weekday"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 "♦"&B3:B&"♥"&A3:A&"♥"&A1&"♦"&D3:D&"♥"&C3:C&"♥"&C1&
 "♦"&F3:F&"♥"&E3:E&"♥"&E1&"♦"&H3:H&"♥"&G3:G&"♥"&G1&
 "♦"&J3:J&"♥"&I3:I&"♥"&I1&"♦"&L3:L&"♥"&K3:K&"♥"&K1&
 "♦"&N3:N&"♥"&M3:M&"♥"&M1, ), , 999^99), "♦")), "♥")))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: you should add an explanation